# Получение переменных из объекта php

Tags: php

Создан объект А. Внутри него в методе создается объект Б (другого класса). Из объекта Б вызывается метод. Можно ли как нибудь получить переменные объекта А, в методе объекта Б, если они не переданы явно и не являются глобальными?

Comment: приведите пример кода

Answer (score 1):

Если брать ваши входные данные, то нет. Возможно с помощью `Reflection` или других хаков, типа приведения объекта к массиву используя SPL, можно получить доступ к свойствам/методам класса вне его контекста, но это плохая практика, использовать ее не советую.

Answer (score 0):

Если свойства объекта А публичные или есть методы, возвращающие их (гетеры), можно передать объект А в объект Б и тогда можно из методов объекта Б получить доступ к свойствам А.

Если передать объект А в объект Б нельзя или у объекта А нет публичных свойств, то доступ получить нельзя. (На самом деле если объект передать можно, но публичных свойств нет, то доступ получить все же можно - через рефлексию, но делать это КРАЙНЕ не желательно. Ну или очень хорошо понимать что и зачем делаете)

Пример

```
class A {
    public $prop;

    public function doWork() {
        $b = new B();
        $b->execute($this);
    }
}

class B {
    public function execute(A $a) {
        echo $a->prop;
    }
}
```

Comment: справедливости ради у объекта А могут быть публичные статики

Comment: справедливости ради этот вопрос звучит, как вопрос с собеседования и вы исказили входные данные.

Comment: @NikitaPimoshenko Я?!

Answer (score -3):

Можно передать в конструктор:

```
class A {
 public function run() {
  $obj = new B($params);
 }
}
```

Можно передать в качестве аргумента метода:

```
class A {
 public function run() {
  $obj = new B();
  $obj->method($params);
 }
}
```

Можно присвоить свойствам класса Б.

```
class A {
 public function run() {
  $obj = new B();
  $obj->params = $params;
  $obj->method();
 }
}

class B {
 public $params;
 public method() {
  // TODO $this->params
 }
}
```

Comment: Вы исказили входные данные задачи, думаю - это просто вопрос с собеседования.